# changing shapes (pro)

Tags: python

Hi I am new to programming and I am trying to write a code that will gather information from the input and apply it to the triangle.

This is my code so far

```
steps = int(input("Size: "))

print('/\\')
for i in range(steps - 1):

    print(" "*i+"  \\")
print(steps * "__" )
```

suppose if the input was three then my program would look like this.

[image: ![enter image description here]

when I want the output to look like this.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my code:

```
steps=input("Size: ")

for i in range(steps):
    j=steps-i-1
    print ' '*j+"/"+' '*i+' '*i+'\\'
print '-'*(steps*2+1)
```

Which is the same thing as below:

```
steps=input("Size: ")

for i in range(steps):
    j=steps-i-1
    print ' '*j+"/"+' '*(i*2)+'\\'
print '-'*(steps*2+1)
```

Comment: wouldnt you need to do steps=int(input

Comment: no, you wouldn't. When you have only input, that cares of the number, but if you have raw_input, then you will need int(raw_input()).

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I think will work. One key thing is that you aren't drawing the left side for all rows after the first, nor account for additional left space needed to align your triangle.

```
steps = int(input('Size: '))

for i in range(steps):
    left_space = steps - i - 1
    inner_space = i
    print('{}/{}\\'.format(' ' * left_space, ' ' * inner_space * 2))
print(steps * '__')
```

**Output**:

```
Size: 2
 /\
/  \
____

Size: 3
  /\
 /  \
/    \
______

Size: 4
   /\
  /  \
 /    \
/      \
________
```

Comment: How would I move the bottom of the triangle a bit higher. Suppose when you write size: 3, the gap from the bottom is to big,

Comment: You would have to use another character that is a higher line than the underscore. One option is the overline character: `‾`.